# In SQL Server 2012, can I use parameters in Rows Preceding to calculate a dynamic moving average?

Tags: parameters, sql-server-2012, moving-average

Stored procedure to calculate dynamic moving average for specified ticker and days:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_MovAvg 
    (@ticker NVARCHAR(6),
     @days INT)
AS
  SELECT 
      @ticker AS Ticker, [Date],
      AVG ([px_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY @ticker, [Date] 
                             ROWS BETWEEN @days PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS moving_avg
  FROM 
      daily_data
  WHERE 
      Ticker LIKE @ticker
  ORDER BY
      Ticker ASC, [Date] DESC
```

I get error msg for avg function when using `@days`

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `ROWS BETWEEN` [needs literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#syntax):

> ```sql
> <window frame preceding> ::=   
> {  
>     UNBOUNDED PRECEDING  
>   | <unsigned_value_specification> PRECEDING  
>   | CURRENT ROW  
> }  
> <unsigned value specification> ::=   
> {  <unsigned integer literal> }
> ```

You could solve this by using `LAG` and lots of `CASE` expressions, or self-joining.
But the easiest is probably dynamic SQL.

- Don't forget to parameterize `@ticker`

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE MovAvg 
    (@ticker NVARCHAR(6),
     @days INT)
AS

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max) = N'
  SELECT 
      @ticker AS Ticker, [Date],
      AVG ([px_Close]) OVER (ORDER BY @ticker, [Date]  -- Did you mean Ticker, [Date]??
                             ROWS BETWEEN ' + CAST(@days AS nvarchar(10)) + N' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS moving_avg
  FROM 
      daily_data
  WHERE 
      Ticker LIKE @ticker
  ORDER BY
      Ticker ASC, [Date] DESC;
';

EXEC sp_executesql
    @sql,
    N'@ticker NVARCHAR(6)',
    @ticker = @ticker;
```